# What is the best way to formulate an average with a vertical criteria and horizontal range in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is the best formula to get the average if **Criteria** is *Vertical* and **Range** is *Horizontal*? I have multiple sheets and workbooks that needs to be averaged based on its criteria and doing manually is not the best way.

I tried using `=AVERAGE(IF($E$1:$Q$1=A2,E2:Q15))` however blank cell are being considered with 0 value and affects the actual average. blank cell should not be calculated on as zero on average.

[image: Please see Screenshot of the template]

*Edit: Added tried/not working formula.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula below will work for cell A2 (and can then be copied down)

```
=SUM(INDEX($E$2:$Q$15,,MATCH(A2,$E$1:$Q$1,0))/COUNTIF(INDEX($E$2:$Q$15,,MATCH(A2,$E$1:$Q$1,0)),">0"))
```

- if you don't have dynamic arrays then it must be entered as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

(if you have Excel 365 then the formula can be shortened

```
=LET(data,INDEX($E$2:$Q$15,,MATCH(A2,$E$1:$Q$1,0)),SUM(data)/COUNTIF(data,">0"))
```

)